# xml file format is wrong, not able to validate it

Tags: xml

I am new to the xml handling.

What is the problem with below xml format, I am not able to open it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<version>1.0</version>
<dat_files_to_be_repaired> D:\dat\server </dat_files_to_be_repaired>
<output_path> D:\dat\server </output_path>
<log_path> D:\dat\server <log_path>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to open it"? What is it that you tried and what happened when you did?

Comment: @nvoigt I tried to validate it by using http://www.xmlvalidation.com/. it is giving some error which I did not get.

Answer (score 1):

The error is

> Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document.

As the error says you need to have on top level element, this should fix the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dat_files_to_be_repaired> D:\dat\server </dat_files_to_be_repaired>
    <output_path> D:\dat\server </output_path>
    <log_path> D:\dat\server </log_path>
</root>
```

Moreover, it should be `</log_path>` for closing a tag not `<log_path>`

Comment: Plz consider accepting the answer by clicking on the hallow checkmark, if my answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your xml file:

- An Xml document cannot obly have a single root element (e.g. `theRoot` below)
- the `log_path` element isn't closed

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<theRoot>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <dat_files_to_be_repaired> D:\dat\server </dat_files_to_be_repaired>
   <output_path> D:\dat\server </output_path>
   <log_path> D:\dat\server </log_path>
</theRoot>
```